# Store webpage for offline viewing ionic 3

Tags: javascript, html, angular, ionic2, ionic3

I was wondering if it's possible to place a web page in localstorage like you can do with images in ionic 2/3 or save it locally for offline viewing. Here is a piece of code I have for accessing a remote book using google docs:

book.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { IonicPage, NavController, NavParams } from 'ionic-angular';
import {SafeResourceUrl, DomSanitizer} from '@angular/platform-browser';

import { Storage } from '@ionic/storage';

@IonicPage()
@Component({
  selector: 'page-view-book',
  templateUrl: 'view-book.html',
})
export class ViewBookPage {
    book: any;
    pdfUrl: SafeResourceUrl;

  constructor(private domSanitizer: DomSanitizer, 
              public navCtrl: NavController, 
              public navParams: NavParams) {

    this.book = navParams.data.book;
    // get url of pdf and embed in iframe from google docs
    this.pdfUrl = this.domSanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl(
        'http://docs.google.com/gview?url='+this.book+'&embedded=true');

  }
```

book.html

```
<ion-header>

  <ion-navbar>
    <ion-title>View book</ion-title>
  </ion-navbar>

</ion-header>


<ion-content padding>

 <iframe width="100%" height="100%" [src]="pdfUrl" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen>
</iframe>


</ion-content>
```

Now what I need is to be able to view the webpage offline(maybe in an iframe) after it loads for the first time. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I highly suggest you use [**Ionic cache service**](https://github.com/Nodonisko/ionic-cache).

> Ionic cache service that can cache almost everything. It caches
>   requests, observables, promises and classic data. It uses Ionic
>   Storage so we support IndexedDB, SQLite (Cordova), WebSQL in this
>   order. It can be used separately in Angular 2 application.

```
npm install ionic-cache @ionic/storage --save
```

Great [**video and article from Simon**](https://ionicacademy.com/ionic-caching-service/).

Comment: It seems to only work for APIs. Will it work for web pages?

Comment: You can cache the data and then you can show those data using existing pages no. I don't see any use case to cache `HTML` here. Because if you fetched the HTML first time then anyway it is in the cache. So you just need to cache the data only.

Comment: Eish I am not sure I am getting you. I tried the above plugin. it won't work for web pages